# Why are multiple Facebook Pixel's loaded on my Shopify page

Tags: facebook, shopify, facebook-pixel

I have a shopify site here: https://www.amrapnutrition.com/
In the admin area, there is a place where you enter your Facebook Pixel ID# and then it automatically adds it in to the site.

My problem is that when the site loads, I am getting two of them loading, as seen in the  section screenshot below. The Pixel ID# entered in the Shopify admin is 39653... as seen in the first line below. I can't figure out what is causing the second Script link to occur. I downloaded the entire site's code and can't find anything that would create that script line or where that number, "16016..." could be coming from.

Not sure anybody could fix this for me, but any help on figuring out what sources can inject this script link in my  might help.

I looked at the other StackOverflow questions about duplicate FB Pixel problems but I think they are a little different from my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally this is because one of your plugins is also loading its own facebook tracking pixel. I've sometimes seen 4 or 5.

If you look at the network inspector it's generally possible to look at the source and initiator column to figure out which plugin is doing the loading.